# wordpress изменить автора записи

Tags: php, wordpress, права

Как изменить в wordpress автора записи если пользователь состоит в группе  editor. Как отобразить у него это поле?

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать через `the_author_meta()` при помощи `user_level`.

the_author_meta:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_author_meta

user_level:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913524/translate-wordpress-user-roles-to-level-0-10

Comment: Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: в зависимости от того, какой результат нужен.

например:

`<p> Автор: <?php
 if ( ( the_author_meta('user_level') > 2 ) && ( the_author_meta('user_level') < 7 ) ) {
  echo the_author_meta('nickname') . 'AND HE IS EDITOR FROM OUR SUPER TEAM';
 }
 else {
  echo the_author_meta('nickname');
 } ?>
</p>`

Comment: Понятно. А как отобразить поле в админке, которое дает возможность изменить автора для юзера - editora. Например user_editor, открыл пост и ему нужно изменить автора этого поста. В sql запросе прописать update user_level = 8?